# how to make a Pixel picture in R

Tags: r, image, plot

I have a data.frame as this:

```
> head(shht)
  tt2 imf           f        a
1   1  c1 0.025735102 461.1430
2   2  c1 0.025735102 336.5967
3   3  c1 0.012977971 334.0539
4   4  c1 0.013013110 303.7454
5   5  c1 0.009130993 301.7031
6   6  c1 0.009153142 287.5305
```

the data is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3bNSNFik5wGNGY4VEQ0TFltM3M)

There are a total of four columns. I want to draw a pixmap. The first column is the horizontal axis, the third column is the vertical axis, and the fourth column is the grayscale value.

I tried the following:

```
> simage=as.image(shht$a,x=cbind(shht$tt2,shht$f))
> image.plot.ts(simage,tt=tt2)
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

the image.plot.ts() is a function from EMD. and the as.image() comes from fields.

Comment: Hello, do you use any package, if so could you provide the package used since the `as.image` is not a base function. I might be wrong but isn't `image.plot.ts` a function associated with timeseries ?

Comment: You need to specify the package you are using, otherwise we can not reproduce your example. This is a good one for pixel maps: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pixmap/pixmap.pdf But going by the error you get you simply need to resize the plot panel in your RStudio.

Comment: the image.plot.ts() is a function from EMD.

Comment: and the as.image() comes from fields.

Comment: the data is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3bNSNFik5wGNGY4VEQ0TFltM3M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `image` function by generating a matrix of your data?

```
x = rep(1:5,5)
y = rep(1:5, each = 5)
d = sample(1:10, length(x),replace = T)

df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, d = d)

mat <- matrix(df[order(df$x, df$y),'d'], 5)
image(mat)
```

---

Or you could make a simple plot of your data, mimicking pixels.

```
plot(x, y, col=d, pch=15, cex=4)
```

---

edit:
I dont fully understand how your data needs to become an image. Since you have only one datapoint per x co-ordinate:

```
id <- "0B3bNSNFik5wGNGY4VEQ0TFltM3M" 
dat <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = tt2, y = f, color=a)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

produces

[image]

Comment: the data is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3bNSNFik5wGNGY4VEQ0TFltM3M)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response. In the data set, the first column and the third column and the fourth column are divided into six groups by the value of the second column. I want to do is in a grid map, the first and third column position a small grid, the fourth column for the gray values of grids, the rest of the grids are white. This gives a gray-scale grid map.

Comment: Therefore, each tt2 should correspond to six gray grid. In this process, I may need to change the value of the third column and the value of the fourth column so that the vertical axis has the appropriate resolution, and the gray scale can be properly reflected. Or, in order to get the effect of grid, I can set the number of pixels to achieve the picture?

Comment: I do want to help but I don't understand what kind of picture you are looking for. You might need to make a simple example for me to get it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a package for direct manipulation of bitmap images. [pixmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pixmap/index.html) It has a range of methods for creating and manipulating them.

One example, directly from the reference manual:

```
library(pixmap)


x <- seq(-3,3,length=100)
z1 <- outer(x,x,function(x,y) abs(sin(x)*sin(y)))
z2 <- outer(x,x,function(x,y) abs(sin(2*x)*sin(y)))
z3 <- outer(x,x,function(x,y) abs(sin(x)*sin(2*y)))


z <- pixmapRGB(c(z1,z2,z3), 100, 100, bbox=c(-1,-1,1,1))
plot(z, axes=TRUE)
```